# How can I use dllmap on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, dllimport

I'm using Xamarin.Android, have a project set up like so

- Native library for Windows (NativeMethods.dll)
- Native library for Android (NativeMethods.so)
- Portable P/Invoke library, DllImport to NativeMethods.dll
- Windows application (uses portable P/Invoke library + Windows native library)
- Android application (uses portable P/Invoke library + Android native library)

Using mono, one could simply use [dllmap](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/) in App.config to remap any DllImports to NativeMethods.dll to NativeMethods.so

I tried, but I can't seem to get this working with Xamarin.Android. I'd like to avoid compiling two MSIL P/Invoke libraries as well as two native ones (one each for Android and Windows).

Here's what my app.config looks like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <dllmap dll="NativeMethods.dll" target="NativeMethods.so"/>
  </configuration>
```

I tried this in the P/Invoke DLL project, the Xamarin.Android application project but it doesn't work anywhere. The only reference I found to my issue is [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24943) similar one for iOS. Has anyone encountered/solved this issue? What am I missing? I'd also be interested if the solution to do this for Xamarin.iOS was any different, because that will be the next platform I need to target.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NativeMethods` (without extension) as the name of the library.

.NET will automatically append `.dll` and Mono will automatically append `.so` when searching for the library.

However for iOS you'll need a dllmap (since the library name must be `__Internal`)

Source: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: I'm not sure if dllmap works for iOS. Have you successfully used it?

Comment: @ananthonline: I haven't personally tried it, no. Feel free to file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a test case if you have problems though, since it should work.